# Unable to install the Synchronization Service. Please see the event log for additional details

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Here I'm trying to install "Microsoft Azure Active Directory Sync Service" but it's displays an error saying that "Unable to install the Synchronization Service. Please see the event log for additional details" so can any one help me out to get this done.

In Event Logs the error shown as

"System.Exception: Unable to install the Synchronization Service. Please see the event log for additional details. ---> Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ProcessExecutionFailedException: Exception: Execution failed with errorCode: 1. Details: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Interfaces: The specified LocalDB instance does not exist. [x89C50107]. . Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.. at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ProcessAdapter.StartProcessCore(String fileName, String arguments, String workingDirectory, NetworkCredential credential, Boolean loadUserProfile, Boolean hideWindow, Boolean waitForExit) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ProcessAdapter.StartBackgroundProcessAndWaitForExit(String fileName, String arguments, String workingDirectory, NetworkCredential credential, Boolean loadUserProfile) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.SqlCmdAdapter.ExecuteCommand(String arguments, NetworkCredential credential) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__17() at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__18() at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ActionExecutor.Execute(Action action, String description) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.InitializeSqlSharedInstance(String sqlLocalDbInstanceOwnerSid, NetworkCredential sqlLocalDbInstanceOwnerCredential, SetupConfig config) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.InstallCore() at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ActionExecutor.Execute(Action action, String description) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SetupBase.Install() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SetupBase.ThrowSetupTaskFailureException(String exceptionFormatString, String taskName, Exception innerException) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SetupBase.Install() at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.UserInterface.SetupAdapter.TypeDependencies.GenericDirectorySyncSetupInstall(String pathToSetupFiles, String installationPath, ProgressChangedEventHandler progressChangedEventHandler) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.UserInterface.UI.WizardPages.InstallOrUpgradePageViewModel.SetupTask(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args) at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.UserInterface.UI.Controls.Wizards.ProgressReportingTaskViewModel.ExecuteAction(Action action, Boolean isProgressIndeterminate)"

Comment: Please include the error entry from event logs in your question.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I've included error in the question have a look @Gaurav

Comment: One of the thing that caught my eye in the error message is this - `The specified LocalDB instance does not exist`. Can you check if LocalDB is installed along with your SQL Server on your computer?

Comment: I don't have SQL Server installed on my system. is it required

Comment: From the error message, it looks that way. You can try by installing SQL Server Express. When you install, please ensure that LocalDB is also installed along with that (I believe you will get an option to do so). HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Something during the installation has gone wrong. The official documentation says:

> You need an account with local administrator privileges on your computer to install Azure AD Sync.
>
> Azure AD Sync requires a SQL Server database to store identity data. By default a SQL Express LocalDB (a light version of SQL Server Express) is installed and the service account for the service is created on the local machine. 
>   SQL Server Express has a 10GB size limit that enables you to manage approximately 100.000 objects.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn757602.aspx

**Note:** Azure AD Sync is replaced by Azure AD Connect. You can read more about Azure AD Connect [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) and [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/06/24/azure-ad-connect-amp-connect-health-is-now-ga.aspx).

Comment: I have installed Sql Server Database both server and client  along with LocalDB on my system. But it is showing the same error.

Comment: What if you remove Sql Server with LocalDB and the AADSync tool and reinstall the **AAD Connect** tool. This is the **new** sync tool. Why stick with the previous sync tool when you are performing a fresh installation.

Comment: What does the event log say? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2684395 how you can show the messages specific for the AAD Sync tool.